# Notepad++/Regex - How to conditionally switch the last 2 lines in a text file

Tags: regex, switch-statement, notepad++, lines

I want to switch the last 2 lines of a file (so that the penultimate one is now the last one and reverse, BUT only in the situation where the penultimate line starts with a c. Preferably using any type of regex since I have to do this on various files.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with notepad++:

```
search: (?<=\n)(c.*)(\r?\n)(.*)\Z
replace: $3$2$1
```

("dot match newline" must not be checked)

Comment: Almost there! This will switch any row starting with `c`. For example `a1\nc2\na3\nc4\na5` will be transformed to `a1\na3\nc2\na5\nc4`, instead of `a1\nc2\na3\na5\nc4`. You have to change the last `$` to `\Z`!

Comment: @psxls: exact! I didn't know that notepad++ was using this syntax.